# Change state of input text in list to 'edit' on double click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i tried to change state using edit button. I'm not sure how to edit it with double click an then save it on clicking save button.I made save function but it is not working as directed. I need the new value to be updated in the list after clicking save

```js
  

      class App extends React.Component {
    
  

         constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[],
      editing:false,
      value: ''
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )

    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, checked:false})
      });
      this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(todo,i){
    return (
      <li className={todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'}>
        <div onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this, i)}>
          <input type="checkbox" className="option-input checkbox" checked={todo.checked} />
          <div key={todo.id}  className="item">
            {todo.Value}
            <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this,i)} className="editmode">edit</button>
            <span className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };

  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
  todoCompleted(i){
     var todo=this.state.todo;
     todo[i].checked =todo[i].checked? false:true;
       this.setState({
         todo:this.state.todo
       });
   };
  allCompleted=()=>{
    var todo = this.state.todo;
    var _this = this
    todo.forEach(function(item) {
      item.className = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo" : "line"
      item.checked = !_this.state.finished
    })
    this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished})
  };
  changeValue(e) {
    this.setState({
    value: this.state.value = e.target.value
  });
}
  edit(i){
    var todo= this.state.todo
    this.setState({
      editing:true,
      value: this.state.todo[i].Value
    });
  };
  save(i){
    var Todo=this.ref.edittodo.value
    var todo=this.state.todo[i]
    this.setState({
      editing:false,
      todo:this.state.todo.concat({Value:todo})

    });
  };
    rendernormal() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
          <div className="lines"></div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
            <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">^</span>
          </div>
          <div className="mainapp">
            <ul className="decor">
              {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    renderform(todo,i) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
        <div className="lines"></div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" ref= "edittodo" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeValue.bind(this)} className="editodo"placeholder='EDIT TODO'/>
          <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">^</span>
          <button onClick={this.save.bind(this,i)}>save</button>
        </div>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <ul className="decor">
            {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    };
    render(){
      if (this.state.editing) {
        return this.renderform()
      }
      else {
      return this.rendernormal()
      }
    };
  }

      

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
    .line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
.newtodo{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I tried some ways but the error i got is **cannot read property 'edittodo' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this.ref` is undefined in this line:

```
this.ref.edittodo.value
```

What you're looking for is `this.refs` ([source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)):

```
this.refs.edittodo.value
```

What's better is to stop using the string as a ref, and use a callback, as explained in the link above:

```
<input type="text" 
       ref={(input) => this.edittodo = input} 
       value={this.state.value} 
       onChange={this.changeValue.bind(this)} 
       className="editodo"placeholder='EDIT TODO'/>
```

And then you can access the input like this:

```
this.edittodo
```

Comment: yeah! got it, can you tell me how do i store the edited value, I'm not able to store the edited value

Comment: the value on click on save button gets stored in input field instead of corresponding list item